# What is the meaning of ", an important step forward"?

Tags: meaning

What is the meaning of ", an important step forward" in the following sentences,

> The antibody was developed in collaboration with two research groups
>   in the US. The team has now established that the antibody can
>   neutralize a lab variant of the virus, ***an important step forward***
>   in the development of a potential antiviral drug against the new
>   coronavirus.

( Source: VIB achieves important milestone in the development of a COVID-19 drug  )

?

Does "The team has now established that the antibody can neutralize a lab variant of the virus, an important step forward" mean "The team has now established that the antibody can neutralize a lab variant of the virus. And that the antibody can neutralize a lab variant of the virus is an important step forward" ?

Does "," in ", an important step forward" mean "and that the antibody can neutralize a lab variant of the virus is" ?

If so, after a ",", I have often seen sentences without conjunctions, subjects and verbs. In this cases, does "," imply the meaning of conjunctions, subjects, and verbs?

Answer (score 2):

The discovery or establishment "that the antibody can.." is the important step forward.

Same as 'a step forward' is important to a baby learning to walk. It's progress.